# What does PSA stand for?

Tags: discussion

I was able to deduce what PSAs seem to be (in the way of 'hey people, this is another VERY IMPORTANT THING we want you to keep in mind') but I could not find what the supposed acronym stands for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Public Service Announcement. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFkzWSFW70M

Comment: Sometimes youtube is so not funny >_<

Comment: Can we adopt moose and squirrel for making of announcements on askbuntu? Nuclear Wessels

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_service_announcement

Answer (score 1):

It also could be:

- Please See Attached
- Personal Service Assistant
- Proxy Signalling Agent

Comment: But usually it means "Public Service Announcement."

Comment: Publicly Screaming moderAtor? ;-)

Comment: @TheLordofTime  I agree 100% but why not :)